# Combining similar strings using R [Text Analysis] [n-gram]]

Tags: r, nlp

Is there any way to get the count of similar strings:

```
"dog is good"
"is good dog"
"good dog is"
"team work"
"work team"
```

Output should be

```
dog is good: 3
team work: 2
```

1> Have tried splitting the words, 
2> reversing the order of words 
3> Applying antijoin and inner join to identify these type of strings in n-gram approach by creating 2 different dataframes. 
However, struggling to get the total count as an aggregate value.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. since the data is huge, having an optimal solution would be a great help.

There is very valid question by a contributor here "@Lime". so to make sure that the objective is very well focused.

so in my case, anything which is exact same... and should not be containing any other text /character to be map against a similar string.

```
"dog is good"
"dog are good"
"are dog good"
```

should be having an output like:

```
"dog is good": 1
"dog are good": 2
```

Comment: For a general solution, you need to define "similar".  Would, for example "is my dog good" match?  How about "dogs are good"?  Or "my question is are dogs good"?

Comment: so in my case anything which is exact same... and should not be containing any other text /character to be map against the similar string... Thanks a lot for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a simple hack:

```
dd<-read.table(text="dog is good
    is good dog
    good dog is
    team work
    work team", sep="\t", as.is=T)

output <- dd%>%
  mutate(V2 = sapply(lapply(strsplit(dd$V1," "), sort), paste, collapse=" "))%>%
  count(V2)
```

Hence the output looks like:

```
           V2 n
1 dog good is 3
2   team work 2
```